# Is $\sum \sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to test for convergence of the series:

- $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{n}\Bigr)$

What i did was

\begin{align*}
\sin\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{n}\Bigr)+ \sin\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\Bigr) + \cdots  & < \pi \biggl( \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \cdots \biggr) \\ &= \pi \biggl( \sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+r}\biggr) =\int\limits_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x} \ dx \\ &= \pi\log{2}
\end{align*}

I think this proves the *convergence* of the series.

- I am interesting in knowing some more methods which can be used to prove the convergence so that i can apply them.

**ADDED:** Note that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} \cdot f\Bigl(\frac{r}{n}\Bigr) = \int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x) \ \textrm{dx}$$

Comment: How did you manage to sum the harmonic series?

Comment: @Willie Wong: Changing *limit of a sum* into an definite integral.

Comment: @Chandru1 : I think the right expression in the added note should be $\lim_n\sum_{r=1}^n\frac 1n f\left(\frac rn\right)$.

Comment: Anyway, the series you have diverges.

Comment: @Andres Caicedo: Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{r = 1}^n\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{r}{n}} \neq \sum_{r = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+r}$$ The left hand side is independent of $n$, the right hand side isn't. There's a piece $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r = n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+r}$ that you are missing when you "applied the formula". If that term were convergent, then it would go away when you take the limit. Unfortunately, the series inside is divergent...

Comment: Nobody has mentioned the standard calculus theorem here; usually called the "limit comparison test" (at least e.g. in Stewart's calculus textbook).  More generally as a consequence of this test, if $a_n$ is any nonnegative sequence with limit $0$, $\sum \sin(a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum a_n$ converges (for the reason that $\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$ goes to $1$ as $t \to 0$).  Perfectly rigorous and no harder to prove than the standard "comparison test" for series of nonnegative terms.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You observed correctly that for small angles $\frac{\pi}{n}$, sin$\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$ is very close to $\frac{\pi}{n}$. As for convergence of $\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$...

Comment: Ah, you beat me to my comment above. Also to be slightly more rigorous, one should note that the error term from approximating $\sin(\pi/n)$ by $\pi/n$ for large $n$ is $O(n^{-2})$, so the error term gives finite contribution to the sum.

Comment: @Willie Yes, this was not an attempt at a rigorous answer. It is actually quite easy to explicitly bound the terms below, so no need for error analysis. But I will leave that to Chandru.

Answer (score 0):

The way of solving the problem is wrong. We know that $\sum \frac1n$ is divergent series and if we apply the comparison test limit form in $\sum \frac1n$ and $\sum \sin\Big(\frac1n \Big)$ we show that both the series  diverge or converge together. then the given series is divergent.